# Specifying the return type of a method of a type class instance based on the type contained by the associated type family instance

Tags: haskell

As part of a thought experiment,
I'm trying to enforce the following properties
for a type family T associated with type class TC
in Haskell:

1. Members of family T with different labels are different types.
2. All T with the same label contain the same type of value.
   (i.e. the label string implies the return type of `val`)

with the following feature:

1. The string representation of the label of a T can be viewed at runtime, but not changed at runtime.

Any ideas?

The closest thing I could get to compile is the following. It satisfies Property 1 and Feature 1
but violates Property 2.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
-- Works, violates Property 2

class TC (l :: Symbol) where
  data T l :: * -> *
  label :: T l v -> String
  val :: T l v -> v

instance TC "age" where
  data T "age" v = T___age v
  label x = "age"
  val (T___age x) = x


-- The return type of val is determined by how one constructs T___age,
-- rather than implied by the "age" label.
foo = T___age 1      -- In GHCi, foo :: Num v => T "age" v
bar = T___age "1"    -- and bar :: T "age" [Char]
```

Is there any way to specify the return type of val on the instance declaration
associated with T___age rather than when the data is constructed? I tried the following,
but it won't match the `Int` in the `T___age` constructor with the `v` returned from val.

```
class TC (l :: Symbol) where
  data T l :: *
  label :: T l -> String
  val :: T l -> v

instance TC "age" where
  data T "age" = T___age Int
  label x = "age"
  val (T___age x) = x
```

The error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘v’ with actual type ‘Int’
      ‘v’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for val :: T "age" -> v at src/Basics.hs:108:3
    Relevant bindings include
      val :: T "age" -> v (bound at src/Basics.hs:108:3)
    In the expression: x :: Int
    In an equation for ‘val’: val (T___age x) = x :: Int
    In the instance declaration for ‘TC "age"
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understand what you want, but maybe this?

```
class TC (l :: Symbol) where
  data T l :: *
  type V l :: *
  label :: T l -> String
  val :: T l -> V l

instance TC "age" where
  data T "age" = T___age Int
  type V "age" = Int
  label x = "age"
  val (T___age x) = x
```

Comment: This seems like it accomplishes what I want. I wasn't aware that it was possible to associate a type synonym with a type class like you can a type family, that's a pretty cool technique. Thank you :).

Comment: @MichaelTaufen Just a note, `type V l :: *` *is* a type family, not a simple type synonym, whose index is `l` - because this type variable is bound in the class head. There is no difference between `class C x where type V x` and `class C x; type family V x`, other than the compiler reminding you to write an instance for `V` when you do so for `C`.